# How to execute a raw sql query with multiple statement with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Is there anyway I can execute a query with multiple statement like the one below, using laravel framework.
I have tried using `DB::statement` but returned a sql syntax error, but when I execute the same query on phpmyadmin I works, its so frustrating.
Please help me.

### EG

```
LOCK TABLE topics WRITE;

SELECT @pRgt := rgt FROM topics WHERE id = ?;

UPDATE topics SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE rgt > @pRgt;
UPDATE topics SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt >= @pRgt;

INSERT INTO topics (title, overview, article, image, lft, rgt)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, @pRgt, @pRgt + 1);

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: I believe you need to use 7 `DB::statement` calls for this, one for each statement

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`DB::unprepared()` should do the trick , laravel prepare and do some stuff for sql queries .
 But instead you can use absolutely raw ones using `DB::unprepared` .

**EG**

```
DB::unprepared('LOCK TABLE topics WRITE;

SELECT @pRgt := rgt FROM topics WHERE id = ?;

UPDATE topics SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE rgt > @pRgt;
UPDATE topics SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt >= @pRgt;

INSERT INTO topics (title, overview, article, image, lft, rgt)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, @pRgt, @pRgt + 1);

UNLOCK TABLES;');
```

It will execute your whole SQL query whether it is single/multiple statements .

Comment: Wow thank you so much, but unfortunately this method doesn't bind values like DB::unprepared('select * from table where id = :id', ['id' => 1]) will throw an sql error.

Comment: Yes that's why it is called unprepared :) so you can't use prepared statements you can try an alternative approach try group all your parameters in an array , treat your query as a string and replace the  '?'  sequentially with the corresponding parameter in the array and then send your string to the DB::unprepared method :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @TheSalamov

I thought to illustrate with general PHP example in Laravel

```
$result = DB::unprepared("LOCK TABLE table1 READ, table1 WRITE, table2 READ, table3 READ;"  
    .  $query_multi_stmt 
    .  " UNLOCK TABLES;");

if ($result > 0 ){  //...if rows affected
           //...do something
}
```